# Google Drive MetadataChangeSet setMimeType for apk file

Tags: android, upload, google-drive-api, apk

I have searched all around but I can't find out the particular mimetype for an apk file for google drive android api.

Can anybody tell what should I use below

```
                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("APK")
                        .setMimeType(///HERE///)
                        .setStarred(true).build();
```

so that I can **upload an apk to google drive**.

NOTE : I had used *setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive")* here but this is not working.

Comment: You are using the correct Mime Type. The MIME type associated with APK files is [application/vnd.android.package-archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package). The problem maybe the way how you're uploading it in Java. Have you tried using the RESTful service for uploading files instead?

Comment: no I am using simple way as shown in this https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos

Comment: Check the logs for debugging.

Comment: @noogui When I use setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive") , it shows me no error and upload the file easily but not in apk format. The type of file become unknown on downloading it from Google drive